# Resolving Overloaded Webserver Issues

Tags: database, scalability

I am new to the area of web development and currently interviewing companies, the most favorite questions among what people ask is:

> How do you scale your webserver if it
> starts hitting a million queries?
>
> What would you do if you have just one
> database instance running at that
> time? how do you manage that?

These questions are really interesting and I would like to learn about them.
Please pour in your suggestions / practices (that you follow) for such scenarios

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How to scale:

- Identify your bottlenecks.
- Identify the correct solution for the problem.
- Check to see you you can implement the correct solution.
- Identify alternate solution and check

Typical Scaling Options:

- Vertical Scaling (bigger, faster server hardware)
- Load balancing
- Split tiers/components out onto more/other hardware
- Offload work through caching/cdn

Database Scaling Options:

- Vertical Scaling (bigger, faster server hardware)
- Replication (active or passive)
- Clustering (if DBMS supports it)
- Sharding

Answer (score 4):

At the most basic level, scaling web servers consists of writing your app in such a way that it can run on > 1 machine, and throwing more machines at the problem.  No matter how much you tune them, the eventual scaling will involve a farm of web servers.

The database issue is way more sticky to deal with.  What is your read / write percentage?  What kind of application is this?  OLTP?  OLAP? Social Media?  What is the database?  How do we add more servers to handle the load?  Do we partition our data across multiple dbs?  Or replicate all changes to loads of slaves?

Your questions call more questions, i.e. in an interview, if someone just "has the answer" to a generic question like you've posted, then they only know one way of doing things, and that way may or may not be the best one.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few approaches I'd take to the first question:

1. Are there hardware upgrades that may get things up enough to handle the million queries in a short time?  If so, this is likely an initial point to investigate.
2. Are there software changes that could be made to optimize the performance of the server?  I know IIS has a ton of different settings that could be used to improve performance to some extent.
3. Consider going into a web farm situation rather than use a single server.  I actually did have a situation where I worked once where we did have millions of hits a minute and it was thrashing our web servers rather badly and taking down a number of sites.  Our solution was to change the load balancer so that a few of the servers served up the site that would thrash the servers so that other servers could keep the other sites up as this was in the fall and in retail this is your big quarter.  While some would start here, I'd likely come here last as this can be opening a bit can of worms compared to the other two options.

As for the database instance, it would be a similar set of options to my mind though I may do the multi-server option first as redundancy may be an important side benefit here that I'm not sure it is as easy with a web server.  I may be way off, but that is how I'd initially tackle this.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use a caching proxy

If you serve identical pages to all visitors (say, a news site) you can reduce load by an order of magnitude by caching generated content with a caching proxy such as **[Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/)** or **[Apache Traffic Server](http://trafficserver.apache.org/)**.

The proxy will sit between your server and your visitors. If you get 10,000 hits to your front page it will only have to be generated once, the proxy will send the same response to the other 9999 visitors without asking your app server again.

Answer (score 0):

probably before developer starting to develop the system,
they will consider the specification of the server
maybe you can decrease use of SEO and block it from search engine to craw it
(which is the task that taking a lot of resource)
try to index everything well and avoid to making search easily

Answer (score -1):

1. Deploy it on the cloud, make sure your web server and webapp cloud ready and can scale across different nodes. I recommend cherokee web server (very easy to load balance across different servers, and benchmarks proves faster than Apache,). For ex, google cloud (appspot) needs your web app to be Python or Java
2. Use caching proxy eg. Nginx.
3. For database use memcache on some queries which are suppose to be repeated.
4. If the company wants data to be private , build a private cloud , Here , Ubuntu is doing very good job at it fully free and opensource : http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/private